# EasyNETQ cluster - IClusterHostSelectionStrategy not working when publishing message

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

I added new RabbitMQ Server & configured my Publisher connections string to with

```
"host=PC1:5672,PC2:5672"

var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString, x => x.Register<IClusterHostSelectionStrategy<ConnectionFactoryInfo>, RandomClusterHostSelectionStrategy<ConnectionFactoryInfo>>());
```

When i publish I`m using `bus.Publish(msg)`

When i publish messages , the messsages are sending to PC 1 only.
How can i make sure that messages will send to both, randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance only creates 1 connection when you instantiate it, but picks that host randomly.

If you really want to send to random hosts you could create 2 bus instances connecting to the 2 different hosts, and pick one of those randomly yourself before you publish.